# Vagrant - Connecting to django server from host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I have been struggling with this for days. Its driving me insane, because all that time I could have spent developing. I installed django inside a Ubuntu VM, and I need to access it from the host (Windows 10), but there seems to be no way to access it. I used puphpet to set it up, heres the part of the config.yaml file which defined the network IP and host:

```
            machines:
                vflm_zpwmfbk4aw05:
                    id: machine1
                    hostname: machine1.puphpet
                    network:
                        private_network: 192.168.56.101
                        forwarded_port:
                            vflmnfp_pjysbxl944a0:
                                host: '9346'
                                guest: '22'
                    memory: '2000'
                    cpus: '1'
```

When I run the django server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It runs fine, but theres no way to access it from the host machine. Pointing my browser to `192.168.56.101:8000` gives me a 404 error. I've tried all kinds of variations of this, changing ports, changing the IP.

Heres whats in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       machine1.puphpet        machine1
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant.vm      vagrant
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Heres the interfaces file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
pre-up sleep 2
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
      address 192.168.56.101
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

I ran a port scanner on `192.168.56.101`, and it detects the apache server running on port 80, but doesn't detect anything on port 8000. Could that be the problem, could apache2 be using the port that the django server would usually use?

EDIT: I think the problem is that the guest port is set to 22. Which is a problem because that ports used by other services, when I try to run the django web server on it, it says its forbidden. And the real problem here is when I change the `config.yaml` file, it doesn't change anything when I reload the VM. Nothing I do to that config.yaml file has any effect. Is there some sorta cache I need to clear?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The problem was with the port forwarding configuration. I solved it by adding this to the Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 3333
```

This means I can connect to the server running on port `8000` on the guest machine, by pointing my host machines browser to port `3333`. So for example, I run the server on the guest machine like this:

```
python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then on my guest machine, I can access it by pointing the browser to here:

```
127.0.0.1:3333
```